# Proper Proguard configuration to keep static inner class

Tags: java, android, proguard, inner-classes

I have the following:

```
public class A extends B {
    static class C {
        Object field1;
        int field2;
        boolean field3;
    }
}
```

I **cannot** get the C class via reflection!

I've tried the following:

```
-keep class com.path.to._class.A$** {*;}

-keep class com.path.to._class.A$* {*;}

-keep class com.path.to._class.A$C {*;}

-keep class com.path.to._class.A$C {
    <fields>;
}

-keep class com.path.to._class.A$C {
    Object field1;
    int field2;
    boolean field3;
}
```

None of the above worked. Am I doing something completely wrong here?

Perhaps its worth mentioning that B extends View...

Comment: Needless to say, without running Proguard this works just fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of those should work (only Object -> java.lang.Object). You can check bin/proguard/seeds.txt to see if they are listed. Otherwise, you might be modifying the wrong configuration file, or there might be a typo in the names.

Comment: For some reason adding the -keepattribute InnerClasses did the work, but why? it messed up other inner classes as well.

Comment: The -keep options preserve the classes with their original names, which is sufficient for normal reflection. The option -keepattributes InnerClasses keeps optional attributes that are only needed for less common types of reflection. So it depends on your code and the errors that you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
-keep public class com.path.to._class.A$C {*;}
```

This is working for me, posting very late but still may help others facing this issue