# Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: c

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase Realtime Database and Storage to save and retrieve data, earlier my app was working so fine but suddenly getting

```
Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: c
```

My concern is I don't have any property called **c** in my whole app

```
Process: com.project, PID: 23884
    b.a.b.m.c: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: c
        at b.a.b.m.t.g0.o.a$a.a(:557)
        at b.a.b.m.t.g0.o.a$a.<init>(:488)
        at b.a.b.m.t.g0.o.a.a(:329)
        at b.a.b.m.t.g0.o.a.i(:166)
        at b.a.b.m.t.g0.o.a.g(:60)
        at b.a.b.m.d.a(:282)
        at b.a.b.m.d.a(:159)
        at e.a.c0.b(:925)
        at e.a.p.a(Unknown Source:4)
        at b.a.a.a.k.b0.run(:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

Comment: please do not downvote... as I'm facing this issue since thursday and here came with hope of some suggestions only

Comment: Well that looks like a problem with the pro guard settings defined for firebase in your app. For that you may have enabled minify. You can check other questions and you can find the answer to this.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this is a good question, given the limited information you have. The reason the identifier is `c` is because ProGuard minifies your code when built, and part of this is remapping your human-readable class names to random short strings. Are you building in debug or release? ProGuard shouldn't run on debug builds, so you can see the actual names if the error occurs there.

Comment: You'll want to disable ProGuard for the Java classes that you use to read from/write to the database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710582/proguard-configuration-for-firebase-ui-library and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard

Comment: special thanks to each and everyone posted your suggestions here and I'm glad that it worked for me, but I would like to know, can I enabled minify for release or not ?