# Android proguard, keep inner class of Inner class

Tags: java, android, android-proguard

Parent question: [Android proguard, keep inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059888/android-proguard-keep-inner-class)

**My problem is with inner class of inner class**

**One of the SDKs** in my android project has a class A, which has two static inner class. They are found to be stripped after applying proguard.

```
public class A{
  ....

  static class B{
    ...
    static class D {
        ....
    }

  }

  static class C{
    ...
  }
}
```

My proguard looks like this

```
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses
-keep class com.xxx.A
-keep class com.xxx.A$*
```

Which prevents class B, C from proguard. But no luck with class D. I have tried `-keep class com.xxx.A$**` as well.

Comment: @TGMCians not working

Comment: Try this `-keep class com.xxx.*$*`

Comment: *$* not working either, But -dontwarn com.xxx.** got my build to succeed. I should work on this later I guess.

Comment: Do you need an expression using wildcards or would you settle for an answer specific to just one class??

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the Class specification as shown in the ProGuard [manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#classspecification).

Try replacing:

```
-keep class com.xxx.A
```

With:

```
-keep class com.xxx.** {*;}
```

I'm using that rule with the following file and it's working fine on Android Studio 2.2.3 with build tools 25.0.1 (just in case those might affect the version of ProGuard being used)

**A.java**

```
package com.xxx;

public class A {
  ....

  public class B {
    ....

    public class C {
    ....
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the only real difference between my file and yours is that my inner classes are public and non-static.

**If that doesn't work**

You can always use a rule without wildcards. The following will do the trick:

```
-keep class com.xxx.A$B$D
```