# innerclass obfuscation code in android studio 4.0(macOs)

Tags: android, obfuscation

innerclass obfuscation code in android studio 4.0(macOs)

B is the internal interface of A.

proguard-rules.pro：

```
...
-keep class A$B
-keepclassmembers class A {
public static <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class A$B {
<methods>;
}
...
```

mapping.txt:

```
...
A$B -> A$B:
    ...
...
```

the name of 'B' becomes 'A$B' after confusion, B becomes the external interface A$B。

Why?

Now, it sdk packaging into aar，other devploer can only use A$B to call B，but i think use A.B to call B。how to do？ 3q。

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,...
-keep class [packagename].A{
    *;
}
-keep class [packagename].A$* {
    *;
}
```

Reference:
[Android proguard, keep inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059888/android-proguard-keep-inner-class)